# bootstrap header (navbar-fixed-top) covers menu items (bs-docs-sidebar)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, header, navbar

this is my website : http://forecast.geertjan.it/

It is based on bootstrap.

on this site, I use both bs-docs-sidebar and navbar-fixed-top.

I use bs-docs-sidebar for a menu on the (right) side, who's menu-items jump to h1-titles, using id.

I use navbar-fixed-top for a fixed header (height : 51px).

When the visitor clicks on a menu-item, the site jumps to the title, but the title is located behind the header. Or, in other words : the header is visible above the title.

how can I make sure, that the title is visible when the visitor jumps to it?

logically, the jumped-title is visible at 51px from the top.

here is an example of a title : `<h1 id="introduction" class="page-header">Introduction</h1>`

I have tried `body { padding-top: 40px; }`, but it doesn't solve my problem.

I have put the bootstrap libraries before my own:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="forecast.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but it doesn't solve my problem.... help

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache, it seems too me that the title is beneth the fixed navbar..